# Xamarin Forms time picker without pop-up?

Tags: xamarin.forms, timepicker

Currently in both iOS and android the time picker works like this: you have a time field, and when you tap it, the time picker pops up and you make your selection.

What I’m trying to find out, in Xamarin forms, is if you can expose the time picker itself as part of the main page’s UI, and not as part of a pop-up. So that you can set the time right on the existing UI without having to load another.

Is that possible?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible, but would love to see it in an upcoming Xamarin version.